# RetroPie with multiple Pi 3s

Tags: pi-3, retropie, cluster

I currently have a Rasp Pi 3 Model B running RetroPie on Raspbian that is wiring well enough, it can play everything pre-N64 fairly well, and can get through many of the N64 games out there with minimal issues. But it really can't advance beyond N64, or even get as far as PSX.

My question is this: I know it's possible to combine multiple Rasp Pis and form a cluster, if I were to do that here would it have any positive effect on the performance of retropie as it tries to run some of the newer consoles?

Follow-up, if someone has done this before could you please point me in the right direction, I have looked, but can't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nonstarter. Without rewriting the software (retropie) to take advantage of the cluster architecture. You would likely also need to rewrite the game ROM to parallelize it. Now estimate how many hours of work that would take, if you value your time at all you will see that you would quickly have spent more than a used PSx would cost.